# Tableau Trusted Authentication Ticket with PHP

Tags: php, curl, tableau-api

I am trying to understand how the Trusted Authentication ticket is meant to work with PHP. I've been looking up different questions and came up with this code

```
$url = 'https://tableau.godigitally.io/trusted/';     
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "username=" . $userid . ""); // define what you want to post    
$response = curl_exec($ch);   
curl_close($ch);   
//echo 'Test: ' . $response;  
echo '<iframe src=', $url, $ticket, 'views/Dashboard2_0/Dashboard1?', $urlparams, '" 
       width="700" height="400">   
  </iframe>';
```

But I get the following error when I run this code
[image]

I have no idea where I'm going wrong. I have confirmed that my server configuration is correct by using the testing techniques described in https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth_testing.htm

Answer (score 0):

To Work with Tableau and web UI , the best way, you should add a Tableau js library to your web application and follow the steps

1. Generate the Ticket from tableau server call ,

**To generate the ticket from tableau server ,first you should add your user to tableau server and follow the below steps**

this is the code sample which you can use to generate the ticket

```
function getTabTicket(tableauServer, username, site){
      return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
              let url = new URL(tableauServer + '/trusted');
              let body = {
                          username: username,
                      };
              if (site) {
                          body['target_site'] = site;
                      }
              let postData = querystring.stringify(body);
                         
              let proto = http;
              if (url.protocol === 'https:') {
                          proto = https;
                      }
              let req = proto.request({
                          method: 'POST',
                          hostname: url.hostname,
                          port:url.port,
                          path: '/trusted',
                          headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
                      }, function (response) {
                              let ticketData = '';
                              response.on('data', function (chunk) {
                                          ticketData += chunk;
                                      });
                              response.on('end', function () {
                                          let contents = {ticket: ticketData};
                                          resolve(contents);
                                      });
                          });
              req.on('error', function (error) {
                        reject(error);
                        console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
                      });
              req.write(postData);
              req.end();
            })
}
```

You can check this library which is open source you can use to generate the Ticket.

https://github.com/aalteirac/jwt-tableau-broker

https://anthony-alteirac.medium.com/tableau-trusted-authentication-the-ticket-broker-cloud-friendly-709789942aa3

After generating Ticket , you have to call the tableau server to get the report .

I am using js library for that .

**Now 2 step is include js using NPM or by reference**

and then you can call the function

var tableuReport = new tableau.Viz(this.reportContainerDiv, fullTableauDashboardUrl, Constants.tableauReportUISettings);

reportContainerDiv // the div element in which you have to render the component

fullTableauDashboardURL = **{tableau_server_url}+"trusted"/{ticektId}/reportsuburl**  // the tableau URL it is in the format

for example your ,
tableau_server_url = "https://tableau-dev-abc.com"
tableauDashboardUrl = "#/site/CovidApp/views/IndiaReport/IndiaReport_v2?:iid=1/"

ticketId = "fjdjadheuihrieywfiwnfih"

So your final URL will be like

fullTableauDashboardUrl = "https://tableau-dev-abc.com/trusted/fjdjadheuihrieywfiwnfih/t/CovidApp/views/IndiaReport/IndiaReport_v2?:iid=1

fullTableauDashboardUrl.replace("#/site", "t");
PS: **we have to replace the **#/site to t****